# Replacing main domain server impact on add-on domains and websites

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain, http-redirect, forward

I'm working on a website that has multple websites installed (via same CMS) and used as international websites.

The server at the moment is connected with a main domain `www.example.com`. International installs are folders in its `public_html.` They are pretty independent of each other.

Now the international domains like example.co.uk are actually defined as add-on domains that redirect to `public_html/uk` folder (which has its own htaccess, and again its CMS installation; files and db).

My question is what would happen if I point `www.example.com` to another server? what would happen if someone tries to access `example.co.uk`?

Ideally I'd like that `public_html/uk` folder to be connected with the domain  `example.co.uk` but yeah setting the DNS to a folder is not possible.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you point your `example.com` to another server, this domain obviously would display content from the new server instead.
If you've set the home/root directory for `example.co.uk` as `public_html/uk` (which you probably have done), this domain will serve that folder as expected and changing the main domain would not affect this.

Comment: Thanks Sykez. But what would then public_html/uk serve? what would be the full domain? 

Any idea, how do I test this is the case without breaking it down completely?

Comment: @superasperatus `public_html/uk` would serve for the domain `example.co.uk`. Isn't that the current setup as well? If not, please do elaborate your current structure. Full domain for main site would be `example.com` and UK site would be `example.co.uk`. If you want to some testing, perhaps you can try [editing your host file](https://support.managed.com/kb/a683/how-to-modify-your-hosts-file-so-you-can-work-on-a-site-that-is-not-yet-live.aspx) and point `example.com` to your new server. Also, do you currently use `example.com/uk` in any way?

Comment: Hey Sykez!Thanks. yup it seems I missed to note that now - the uk site ends up at `www.example.com/uk`.
An expansion: At the moment this is the flow for international website:

domain: `example.co.uk` point's to a server (where main domain is example.com) and that UK domain is added as an add-on domain and redirects to `public_html/uk` which is again a seperate install and all and it ends up as `www.example.com/uk`


Now I'm wondering what would happen if I just remove the www.example.com and point to another server. what would happen to public_html/uk -where would it end?

Comment: @superasperatus Aah! So going directly to `example.co.uk` redirects the URL to `example.com/uk`, correct? In this case, if you move `example.com` to another server, and this server does not have a `/uk` directory, you'll probably get an error 404. The content on the old server would be completely inaccessible since no domains are pointing to any content in this server.

Comment: Yup, thats the pickle... Any idea how to make it accessible? One more note, I will not move the content of `example.com`, I'll just point the domain `www.example.com` to another server where we built another site. The content will be there. But I'd assume it's messed up again. Again, ideally I'd like that `public_html/uk` folder to be connected with the domain  `www.example.co.uk` but yeah setting the DNS to a folder is not possible.... thanks. :)

Comment: @superasperatus Ideal option would be then to set the web root folder for `example.co.uk` domain to `public_html/uk`, like I said in the answer. And then have `example.com/uk` do a redirection to `example.co.uk`. This is possible. DNS can't be pointed to a folder, but it can be pointed to a server, and the server can point to any folder it wants really.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sykez! :)